# What does this escape function do?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've come across this regex in a [search results pagination tutorial](https://itnext.io/back-end-pagination-with-nodejs-expressjs-mongodb-mongoose-ejs-3566994356e0), but it doesn't really explain what function the regex helper (they call "escapeRegex") provides.

```
string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
```

Can anyone explain what it does (or is trying to do)?

Comment: Note that `,`, `#` and `\s` (whitespace) are nnot special in JS regex that does not support free spacing (comment) mode, so no idea why these chars are escaped. Also, `-` is not special outside a character class, it should not be escaped either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, it puzzled me as well. Honestly, the only explanation I have is that it's escaping input that would be regex but it `escapeRegex` means "this is the regex for replacing stuff" or "escape stuff using regex". Whatever it's escaping *for* would require escaped `#` and `,` and spaces as well as some characters that happen to overlap with special characters in regular expressions. I visited the link and it's not even much clearer (at least without reading a lot more). It describes it as "Function uses Regular Expressions (RegEx) and it escapes a lot of characters."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually, I found the actual usage. It's `new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');` So, it *does* take input and convert it to regex. I'm not sure why, considering they strip away anything regex related. It seems like a weird way to do case-insensitive plain-text search.

Comment: @VLAZ That means there is a bug in that code.

Comment: Yeah I thought that tutorial seemed a bit iffy, for what it was trying to do. I'll disregard that part.

Comment: I've also just realised that lodash has a regexEscape function, and I'm already using lodash elsewhere, so I'll just use that I think, if/when I need it.